# Visualforce Caching With URL Rewriter

Tags: visualforce, urlrewriter, force.com-sites, caching

I have a URL rewriter running on sites which essentially maps pretty URLs to a single Visualforce page which takes a standard ID parameter.

If I enable caching for the page with `cache='true'` in the page tag, will the system cache versions for each URL used, or will it just cache whatever record happens to be accessed first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All caching is based on the pretty URL (what you see in the browser). Query strings count as part of the cache key, so these URLs would be different values:

```
http://www.mysite.com/page1?a
http://www.mysite.com/page1?b
```

Pages that are URL rewritten as eligible for caching. If you don't specify a cache attribute, it defaults to 10 mins (for public sites).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this comment](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Visualforce-page-caching-issue/td-p/240859/page/2), unique parameters in the query string do not go back to cache (which is a good thing). So you shouldn't have a worry there about serving incorrect page results.

I couldn't find any reliable documentation or posts about caching in conjunction with a URLRewriter though. I think you'll have to test it. I would guess that either URL-rewritten pages are ineligible for caching altogether (seems somewhat unlikely) or that they are cached based on the pretty URL rather than the end parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think that experimentation will be the way forward with this.